# Efficient way to find primitive root without prime factorization

Tags: algorithms, prime-numbers, exponentiation, prime-factorization, primitive-roots

I was wondering if there is a more efficient brute-forcing approach to find any primitive root of number $p$ without prime factorization.

My approach is as follows:

1. Get a random residue class $[x]$ smaller than $p$.
2. Set `exponent` to $1$.
3. Calculate `result = [x]^exponent mod p`.
4. Check if `result` is $1$.
5. If `result` is $1$, check if `exponent` is $p-1$.
6. If condition 5 is true, we have found a primitive root.
7. If condition 5 is not true, we get a new random residue class $[x]$ smaller than $p$.
8. In each iteration, increase `exponent` by $1$.

Comment: By the way: you could at least stop your algorithm at $(p-1)/2$. If $x$ is not a primitive root modulo $p$, its order in $\left(\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}\right)^\times$ is guaranteed to be a proper divisor of $p-1$.

Comment: From [these answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156213/practical-method-of-calculating-primitive-roots-modulo-a-prime) it looks like you are out of luck.