# Verify that $x$ is a primitive root modulo $n$

Tags: number-theory, primitive-roots

I have a question.

How can we the quickest to test whether $x$ is a primitive root modulo $n$?

On the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n#Finding_primitive_roots) I found information about a possible algorithm.

This algorithm, however, must know all the divisors.

I found the question: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156213/practical-method-of-calculating-primitive-roots-modulo-a-prime), but I did not understand much (I need test number $x$).

Can you think of something?

Can this be done in a polynomial time?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}/(n\mathbb{Z})^*$ is not always a cyclic group, so what does your question *really* mean?

Comment: $x\in\mathbb{Z}/(p\mathbb{Z})^*$ is a generator iff $$x^{\frac{p-1}{q}}\neq 1\pmod{p}$$ for every prime divisor $q$ of $p-1$.

Comment: And assuming GRH, there is a generator for $\mathbb{Z}/(p\mathbb{Z})^*$ in the first $C\log^2(p)$ elements for any prime $p$ large enough.

Comment: There is no faster way?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. A random element (better if *not that random*, i.e. better avoiding perfect powers) has a positive probability to be a generator, hence you may just test them till getting a generator. GRH ensures this approach gives a generator pretty soon.

Comment: And you have to perform a test for every *prime* divisor, not every divisor.

Comment: Without the factorization of $p-1$ , it is probably impossible to determine the order, unless we use a quantum computer.

Comment: How large is the prime you have to deal with ?

Comment: This is a theoretical question. Even the Shor algorithm will be sufficient. Thanks for your attention!